# Adjust font size so text always shows

Tags: svg

I have a single line of text centered in my svg at a fixed size.

I'm trying to make the text always show regardless of the text length or parent's dimensions by lowering the font-size (but never getting larger than the specified size).

Is this possible?

```
<div style="width:100px;height:20px;resize:both;overflow:hidden">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<text font-size="15px" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" x="50%" y="50%">Dynamic Text</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the text added? Server-side or with Javascript client-side?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution: I'm putting the text in a `<symbol>` element and I' changing the viewBox of the `<symbol>` element in JavaScript. This works because the width and the height of the SVG element are the same

```js
sTxt.setAttributeNS(null,"viewBox",`0 0 100 ${txt.getComputedTextLength()}`)
```

```css
svg{width:90vh;background:#d9d9d9;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<symbol id="sTxt" viewBox="0 0 100 16">
<text id="txt" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="hanging" x="50" y="0">Dynamic Text soooo long</text>
</symbol>
  <use id="u" xlink:href="#sTxt" width="100" y="50" />
</svg>
```

If the width and the height of the SVG are different  you have to take this in account:

```js
sTxt.setAttributeNS(null,"viewBox",`0 0 100 ${.5*txt.getComputedTextLength()}`)
```

```css
svg{width:90vh;background:#d9d9d9;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<symbol id="sTxt" viewBox="0 0 100 16">
<text id="txt" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="hanging" x="50" y="0">Dynamic Text soooo long</text>
</symbol>
  <use id="u" xlink:href="#sTxt" width="100" y="50%" />
</svg>
```